# htaccess returns Internal Server Error

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^api/list/episode/([^/]*)$ /api/list/episode.php?season=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^api/script/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /api/script/?season=$1&episode=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The rewrite rule for the `api/list/episode` comes up with an `Internal Server Error` I'm not sure why but the other rule works but I have tried to change

**this**
`http://domain/api/list/episode?season=1`

**to this**
`http://domain/api/list/episode/1`

Is it is right for me to place the .htaccess in my root for all directory changes?

Comment: Apache normally provides a detailed error message so you don't have to guess but it won't display in on screen. You just need to check the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of looping. Change that rule slightly:

```
RewriteEngine on 

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^api/list/episode/([^/]+)/?$ /api/list/episode.php?season=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^api/script/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /api/script/?season=$1&episode=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of your rules. The two `/api/` rules should go before the routing-to-php-extension rule. This is because `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` actually inspects inner path elements so it could mistaken `/api/list/episode/1` as `/api/list/episode.php/1` as "exists", then you tack on a .php *to the end*, which makes it: `/api/list/episode/1.php`. It goes through the rewrite engine and the same thing happens again, and then the loop goes on and on.

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^api/list/episode/([^/]*)$ /api/list/episode.php?season=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^api/script/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /api/script/?season=$1&episode=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

You can also try changing you -f check to:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f
```